BJJ beginner training
There is a 10th planet bjj that opened 10 min away from where I live a few months ago and the reviews are just amazing. I would like to sign up and try it out in january as my job is really intense until January (electrical engineer)
I am in my 20s, 6"2, 310lb guy. I have moderate asthma. I go the the gym 3 times per week to lift weights for 1-1.5 years now, I have been to a physio and I am not very flexible or mobile. I would like to start working a bit on to prepare before, what kind of weight exercises do guys do, what kind of stretches, what kind of conditioning.
I would really appreciate the help.

Stretching is always good. Squats, lunges, crunches, shrimping, crocodile crawls, granby rolls. Shoulder circles, running on the spot, touch your toes, try to do the splits, all that good stuff. You can do a lot of good exercises over a yoga ball or punching bag, knee on belly and that sort of thing.

This is actually a common concern people have before joining a martial arts school of any sort, especially one which has a reputation of being very physically demanding. Usually the reason is that they just don't want to look so weak and out of shape to the others there.
Here's the important thing to realize. Each one of them at that school was once you. They each came into it physically unprepared. You can ask them. Each one will say the same thing about how they couldn't even keep up with the rest of the class and had to take lots of breaks during the class.
Over time, they rose to the level of where they needed to be. Most are still on that path, not yet satisfied with their physical conditioning. I don't know anyone who ever is. They are their own worst critics. Every one of them are. They each have things they're working on, and for them it's all about their personal growth. They don't criticize others or look down on them. They know how bad they were when they first came in, and they understand it takes time.
The only thing they might actually notice about you would be how much you've improved over time. Otherwise, they don't care. You don't really matter to them, and they're not thinking about you at all.
When I was in college, I had a martial arts class that I taught. I had a handful of regular students and occasionally had some walk-ins show up just to see what it was like.
One day, a couple big guys came in. They were tall and muscular, big shoulders, not a lot of fat on them. They said they were on the football team at the university I was in (American football). And they explained that the reason they were curious about my class was because they wanted to improve their physical fitness in various ways that they thought martial arts could give them, in order to round out their training.
I said to them that, looking at how well conditioned they appeared to be, they could teach me a thing or two about physical training. I said to them that I doubted the class would be challenging to them at all. But they decided to try it out anyway.
Right away, they were struggling. I could see them trying real hard to get it right and to keep up with the rest of the class. They were laughing at how out of shape they seemed to be, doing the things we did. And honestly, I was amazed myself to see that. I and my students weren't buff at all. We were thin and not very muscular.
At the end of the class, they said that it was the most physically challenging workout they ever had. They came back the next class a couple days later laughing at how their legs still haven't recovered from the first class. They said their legs were so stiff they had trouble even walking up the steps that day to get in. And these were almost pro level athletes. They said they almost had to puke during that first class. Haha!
Well, that goes to show you. No matter how well prepared you are, no matter how good your physical conditioning is ahead of time, the class you're going to take will have you moving in ways you aren't used to and aren't prepared for. Yes, you can train ahead of time and condition your aerobic stamina and maybe lift weights and practice stretching. All of that will help to some degree. But, when you take that class for the first time, it's going to kick your butt. It's because you're going to be doing things in that class which are specific to the training there, not the general sort of conditioning that you would do on your own.
The general things that you might work on ahead of time to prepare yourself aren't necessarily wasted effort, but it won't really prepare you for those things the school does which you haven't trained. And without first training in that stuff, you won't know how to prepare for it.
So the bottom line is this. Just go to the class and start up. Don't make it a big deal. Don't be anxious about not being physically fit or in shape. They'll take you as you are, and they'll work with what you got. You won't die, probably. Although on that subject, definitely get to a doctor and have a physical first and ask if strenuous exercise is okay for you, you weighing over 300 pounds. That is always a good idea no matter how much anyone weighs.
As for your work and how you want to reach a lull in your work demands before you start up with a martial arts school... I think that's also a common theme with career adults in their early stages of their career. Career takes over from college graduation onward. It's easy to lose yourself in your career. You'll put off joining that school until you feel like you have free time again.
The problem with that way of thinking about things is that people who think that way usually never join the martial arts school they want to join. It's because career demands never end if you let them. If you don't prioritize whatever thing you want to do in life, career just has a habit of taking over your entire schedule. You'll be so tired working overtime all the time that you just have no energy to do anything else. You have to want to do martial arts and make it non-negotiable and non-preemptible. This is something that you'll put in your calendar, and you just have to work your career around those hours that you're in martial arts class. In your mind, it should be something sacred, something solid that you just have no choice but to do. So the rest of your life has to work around it.
If you don't think of it that way, you'll find that it won't work. Your career will always push hard on you to do more overtime. There will be deadlines. There will be managers telling you that things must be done by tomorrow or whenever. And that won't ever end for you, if you let it.
You'll have to learn to say no. If you do that enough, they'll realize you're not the guy they can push around like that. They'll look for someone else eventually. If you're estimating your work will take 2 weeks to do, and you have a habit of taking longer all the time, then you need to learn how to be honest with your managers and with yourself. It's not going to take 2 weeks. It will be done in 6 weeks, instead.
In my experience as an electrical engineer, it really is a matter of speaking truth to management about the time needed to get things done. Don't try to be the hero. Heroes on the job are those who envision themselves getting things done in record time. But in order to do that, they have to work 80 hours a week or more. They think it's "possible" to do that, if everything works out perfectly and they stick to that 80 hour schedule. They want to be seen as formidable in the workplace, someone better than everyone else.
Don't do that, because it's almost guaranteed you won't be able to make the deadline. You will find it's impossible to live up to your own ideal if you make it so difficult to achieve. Missing a deadline will force you to drop everything in your life and just work around the clock. And by missing the deadlines habitually, you are assessed as unreliable and slow by your manager, which means you might not get raises and promotions despite being the hardest working engineer in the company. It's something engineers are never taught. They have to learn it the hard way.
So tell your managers how long it will really take, given that you work 40 hours a week. And add 50% to that time estimate, because everyone tends to be too optimistic about their ability to get things done on time. Be honest with them, even though you know they won't like hearing what you're saying. They may decide to find someone else to do the cool things instead of you. Or they may cut back on what features must be complete in order to make the deadline. But that's a tradeoff you have to be okay with if you want to have any life outside of work.
In other words, don't put it off. Join the school this week. Don't worry about starting after the holidays or after work calms down, either. And make this something you can't change about your life and your schedule. Everything needs to work around it.
Hope that helps.

Thank you very much for this reply!
